# Send SMS failed via Android Device

Tags: android

I am writing an app in which i am trying to send SMS to a Recepient, but whenever i do click on Send, getting message:- SMS faild, please try again later!

Either i am using Emulator or Android Device....

Like you can see in below screen shot, here i am trying to send message to Pratik, which is saved in my Phonebook Contacts, but whenever i am trying to message to Pratik not able to send message to Pratik

Please see below screen shot, like you can see, here i am trying to send message to Rahul...

Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Please check below code:

```
    private TextView name;
private ListView list;
private Database db;
private Contact contact;
ImageButton buttonSend;
EditText textSMS;

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editor);

    // bind GUI components
    this.name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editor_name);
    this.list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.editor_list);

    // check if contact id is valid
    this.db = new Database(getContentResolver());
    int contactId = getIntent().getIntExtra(CONTACT_ID, NO_CONTACT_ID);
    this.contact = this.db.getContact(contactId);
    if (this.contact == null) {
        finish();
    }
    this.name.setText(this.contact.getName());

    // pre-load information about all account types
    AuthenticatorDescription[] authTypes = AccountManager.get(this).getAuthenticatorTypes();
    for (AuthenticatorDescription authDesc : authTypes) {
        this.map.put(authDesc.type, authDesc);
    }

    // bind list events
    this.list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    this.list.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

    // create the GUI
    updateView();


    saveGreeting = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.greeting);
    saveGreeting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            customGreeting(v);
        }
    });
    buttonSend = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
    textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();

          try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(CONTACT_ID, null, sms, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `recepient = name.getText()` how is that supposed to work ?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use recipient name to send message , use mobile number to send message .

Get contact number from contact list and use that contact number instead of name in sendTextMessage function.

Comment: so buddy is it not possible to send message to selected friend?

Comment: It is possible but you have to set number instead of name. You have to set name to your view to show details to user but need to pass number in function for sending message.

Comment: first of all please get contact number from contact list and stored it in one string and pass that string into sending message function